# Resolving object with List of different implementations as constructor parameter using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have the following constructor:

```
public DataImporterService(IList<IDataValidator> dataValidators,     IList<IDataComparer> dataComparers, IList<IDataStorage> dataStorages)
        {
            _dataValidators = dataValidators;
            _dataComparers = dataComparers;
            _dataStorages = dataStorages;
        }
```

and this is my registration:

```
Component.For<IDataComparer>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfRecordComparer>().Named("planOfRecordComparer"),
                Component.For<IDataComparer>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfExecutionComparer>().Named("planOfExecutionComparer"),
                 Component.For<IDataComparer>().ImplementedBy<BomComparer>().Named("bomComparer"),
                Component.For<IDataStorage>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfRecordStorage>().Named("planOfRecordStorage"),
                Component.For<IDataStorage>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfExecutionStorage>().Named("planOfExecutionStorage"),
                Component.For<IDataValidator>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfExecutionValidator>().Named("planOfExecutionValidator"),
                Component.For<IDataValidator>().ImplementedBy<PlanOfRecordValidator>().Named("planOfRecordValidator"),
                Component.For<IDataValidator>().ImplementedBy<BomValidator>().Named("bomValidator")
```

but is it possible to register the components in another way not needing to specify each and every implementation of IDataComparer,IDataValidator and IDataStorage? Like in a more generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is how i made it work:

First of I used a collectionresolver:

```
 container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

To register all classes that implements `IDataComparer` , `IDataStorage` , `IDataValidator`

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Validator")).WithServiceFirstInterface(),
Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Comparer")).WithServiceFirstInterface(),
Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(x=>x.Name.EndsWith("Storage")).WithServiceFirstInterface()
```

Then I was able to resolve my class:

```
public DataImporterService(IDataValidator[] dataValidators, IDataComparer[] dataComparers, IDataStorage[] dataStorages)
        { }
```

So when Castle Windsor tries to resovle the DataImporterService it grabs all classes that implements the injected interfaces, construct an array, put them in the array and provide the array as the value for the dependency.

This is provided in the documentation [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **Auto-registration** (AKA convention-based configuration)?

If so, based off the example in section 10.1.2 of [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), you should be able to do something like

```
container.Register(AllTypes
    .FromAssemblyContaining<PlanOfExecutionComparer>()
    .BasedOn<IDataComparer>());
```

Comment: Was just writing up the same answer, but I'll include the [link to the docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md).

Comment: Great! But now I get a problem resolving the
    `DataImporterService(IList<IDataValidator> dataValidators,     IList<IDataComparer> dataComparers, IList<IDataStorage> dataStorages)`

It throws a:

`Component Api.Services.DataImporterService has a dependency on System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Api.Contracts.IDataValidator], which could not be resolved.`

And I have registered a collectionresolver...